# Mozilla WebExtension : local storage works but sync storage doesn't

Tags: javascript, firefox, storage, mozilla

I'm developing a simple web extension for Mozilla Firefox.

The following code works stupendously :

```
browser.storage.local.set({activated: true});
browser.storage.local.get('activated').then(res =>{
    console.log(res.activated);
});
```

But my goal is to sync the data acros all devices, so I converted it into :

```
browser.storage.sync.set({activated: true});
browser.storage.sync.get('activated').then(res =>{
    console.log(res.activated);
});
```

And...does not work. Why?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set), `set` is an async function that returns a promise. Have you tried checking/waiting for the result of the promise before trying to get the new value?